# Exception in CheckExists of quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net

I am getting the below exception intermittently when calling the below method `CheckExists` in .net 6 application, Could you please help?

I am also getting similar exceptions in StoreTrigger, StoreJob, and JobExists as well.

```
services.AddSingleton<IQuartzSchedulersManager, QuartzSchedulersManager>();
services.AddTransient<IQuartzBuilder, QuartzBuilder>();

        private readonly IQuartzBuilder _quartzBuilder;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="quartzBuilder"></param>
        /// <param name="triggerSelector"></param>
        public InternalJobsScheduler(
            IExecutionContextFacade context, 
            IQuartzBuilder quartzBuilder)
        {
            _context = context;
            _quartzBuilder = quartzBuilder;
        }


 private async Task<IScheduler> GetSchedulerForTenant(string tenantId, bool skipCreateIfNotExists)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInfo($"Quartz - QuartzBuilder.GetSchedulerForTenant tenant '{tenantId}'");
                if (_quartzSchedulerManager.Schedulers.TryGetValue(tenantId, out var scheduler))
                {
                    _logger.LogInfo($"Quartz - QuartzBuilder.GetSchedulerForTenant scheduler for '{tenantId}' name: '{scheduler.SchedulerName}' instance: '{scheduler.SchedulerInstanceId}'");
                    return scheduler;
                }

var scheduler = await _quartzBuilder.GetSchedulerForTenant(_context.TenantId.ToString());
await scheduler.CheckExists(jobKey); //exception on this line
```

**Quartz.net version: 3.5.0

Exception Details:**

> problemId: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception at
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport+d__202.MoveNext
>
> type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>
> assembly: Quartz, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4
>
> method:
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport+d__202.MoveNext
>
> outerType: Quartz.JobPersistenceException
>
> outerMessage: Couldn't check for existence of job: Execution Timeout
> Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.
>
> outerAssembly: Quartz, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4
>
> outerMethod:
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport+d__202.MoveNext
>
> innermostType: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>
> innermostMessage: Unknown error 258
>
> severityLevel: 3
>
> Exception: Couldn't check for existence of job: Execution Timeout
> Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.
>
> FormattedMessage: AutomationDiagnostics : Management.Quartz.Service -
> InternalScheduleCommandHandler (x1) - Exception thrown when handling
> the schedule command: Couldn't check for existence of job: Execution
> Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding. :
> automation-management-quartz-deployment-67dfcc5c6-gkhbd : Couldn't
> check for existence of job: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout
> period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
> not responding. : Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period
> elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
> responding. / Unknown error 258 : at
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CheckExists(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder
> conn, JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String
> lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator, Nullable`1 requestorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator, Nullable`1
> requestorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Automation.Management.Adapters.Repositories.InternalScheduler.InternalJobsScheduler.Schedule(InternalScheduleType
> type, String jobId, String whenOptions, String payload, IDiagnostics
> logger) in
> /src/Management/Automation.Management.Adapters/Repositories/InternalScheduler/InternalJobsScheduler.cs:line
> 136 at
> Automation.Management.Quartz.Service.Handlers.InternalScheduleCommandHandler.HandleMessage(InternalScheduleCommand
> message, IReceivedMessageContext context, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> /src/Management/Automation.Management.Quartz.Service/Handlers/InternalScheduleCommandHandler.cs:line
> 57 :
>
> InnerExceptions: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed
> prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> / Unknown error 258
>
> Message: Management.Quartz.Service - InternalScheduleCommandHandler
> (x1) - Exception thrown when handling the schedule command: Couldn't
> check for existence of job: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout
> period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
> not responding.
>
> StackTrace at
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CheckExists(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder
> conn, JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String
> lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator, Nullable`1 requestorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator, Nullable`1
> requestorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Automation.Management.Adapters.Repositories.InternalScheduler.InternalJobsScheduler.Schedule(InternalScheduleType
> type, String jobId, String whenOptions, String payload, IDiagnostics
> logger) in
> /src/Management/Automation.Management.Adapters/Repositories/InternalScheduler/InternalJobsScheduler.cs:line
> 136 at
> Automation.Management.Quartz.Service.Handlers.InternalScheduleCommandHandler.HandleMessage(InternalScheduleCommand
> message, IReceivedMessageContext context, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> /src/Management/Automation.Management.Quartz.Service/Handlers/InternalScheduleCommandHandler.cs:line
> 57